# Removing HTML arrows from homepage

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-7

Some odd arrows are appearing on my site, you can see them above the heading tag below:

[image]

I've tried using Chromes developer tools to find what class/id they are but can't locate them?

You can see them below the fold at: https://www.workbooks.com/

How can I remove these for good!?

Comment: styles.css, line 608

Comment: Thanks, can you suggest how to remove it using internal CSS since it takes me a week or so for my external CSS changes to flush through?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
#homepage-full .node-homepage {
    background: none !important;
}
```

Comment: !important should not be used (if possible), it completely voids any attempt to create sensible CSS.

Comment: The following seems to work just as well:

#homepage-full .node-homepage {
  background-image: none;
}

How did you figure this out!?

Comment: What do you mean how did he figure this out, you gave us the code?

Comment: you can use the developer tools of your browser (by clicking F12) and check the single elements of your page

Answer (score 0):

`<article class="node-3 node node-homepage node-promoted view-mode-full clearfix">` has a background image of `url("../images/wb_steps.png") repeat-x scroll 0 88px transparent`

Remove this

```
.node-3.node.node-homepage.node-promoted.view-mode-full.clearfix {
    background-image: none;
}
```

Or remove line 609 in your `style.css`

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway I can remove it using internal CSS? As it can take a week or so for external style sheet changes to get flushed through.

Comment: Yes, the code I provided will remove this background-image, if you place this in your code somewhere where it will be executed AFTER the external CSS file, then it will counter-act the background image, or use inline styling: `<article style="background-image: none;" class=...>`

Comment: Have tried adding your css at the bottom of my inline styles and had no luck. 

I didn't use the <article> tag so it's picking it up from somewhere else. 

Tried adding <article style="background-image: none;" class="node-3.node.node-homepage.node-promoted.view-mode-full.clearfix"> above where the arrows appear but that didn't seem to work either?

Comment: No, what you're attempting to do won't work, if the HTML is being generated then you can't use inline styling.

You could just remove the image that it's referencing from the directory until you can update the external stylesheets?

../images/wb_steps.png - just delete the actual image until you can update the sheets.

Comment: Thanks Jack, I used: #homepage-full .node-homepage { background-image: none; } which seemed to do the trick (see below)